# How to get current cart items for logged in user

Tags: magento-1.9

Following is my code:-

```html
 try
            {
              $store = $this->_getStore();
              Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store->getId());
              $customer_ID = 3;
              $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_ID);

              // load quote by customer
              $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer_ID);

              $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
              $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                         // set the current store ID
                         ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                         // load the product object
                         ->load(3);

               // Add Product to Quote
               $quote->addProduct($product,1);

               // Calculate the new Cart total and Save Quote
               $quote->collectTotals()->save();
    
               return json_encode(array("", $quote->getId()));
               
            }catch(Exception $e)
            {
                return $e->getMessage();;
            }
```

Using this the product is getting added in cart successfully and returning quote_id, but using this id i want to fetch current cart items details for currently logged in user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get cart item details:

```
$quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote();
$value = [];
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
$value[]= array (
 'id' => $item->getSku(),
 'quantity' => $item->getQty(),
 'price' => $item->getParentItemId()?  $item->getParentItem()->getPrice(): $item->getPrice()
  );
  }
```

Comment: i am posting another question can you please help me out with it also. I will provide you the link of the question shortly, will really appreciate.

Comment: Biplab this is the link to the question:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185236/editing-customer-address-based-on-address-id-and-customer-id-in-magento

Comment: Thank you! yeah sure. i will be posting soon

Comment: Visited today for your question that you posted. Guess you have got the solution :)

Comment: yup biplab, but still wondering on one question how will I display reviews and rating given by perticular customer.