# Editing customer address based on address id and customer id in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

can anyone suggest me how can I update customer address based on address id and customer id. I have tried searching it but it is saying that edit address is not possible even I tried also it is not happening.

I think it might be possible through sql query, but I dont know what sql query to write. So can someone help me. Really will appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
// change these IDs to match your customer and address
$customerId = 136;
$addressId = 92;

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$address = $customer->getAddressById($addressId);
$address->setStreet('123 Main Street');
$address->setCity('Anytown');
$address->save();
```

If you need ways to obtain address IDs, please let me know what you are trying to accomplish and I can let you know the best way to do so.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try this just now and will let you know if it works. I hope so it works :) will update you soon

Comment: Hey, bro thanks a lot for your code it worked like a charm. Really it was very helpful. In future if I find some problem I will definitely approach you.